# Record fetch from database after click on drop down list and display in text box in codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

You all guys are doing great work really appreciate. I have issue in codeigniter to fetch data from database after clicked on drop down list and display in text box. I uploaded the image below to better understand the my issue .In image i have to select single than it will get record from database, Same think on Multiple also.I am not good in codeigniter. Please help me in this.[image]

**Controller**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('model_Details');
        $results = $this->model_Details->retrive1();
        $data['posts'] = $results;

        $this->load->view('organization',$data );       
    }
```

**Model**

```
class Model_Details extends CI_Model{

public function __construct()
        {
            parent:: __construct();
            $this->load->database();

        }


public function retrive1()
{


$this->db->select('Fname,Lname,age,mobile');

$this->db->where('Id', '1');
$this->db->from('details');
$q = $this->db->get();
return $q->result();
}
```

**view**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="title">
  <p><strong>Website</strong></p>
  <select  style="width:150px;" name="website" >
    <option>Select</option>
    <option >Single </option>

  <option>Multiple </option>
</select>

  </div>
</div>


    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="title">

  <p><strong>Fname</strong></p>



<input type="text" name="Fname" style="width:100px;" value=''>


  </div>
</div>



    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="title">
  <p><strong>Lname</strong></p>

   <input type="text" name="Lname" style="width:100px;" value=''>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="title">
  <p><strong>age</strong></p>



   <input type="text" name="age" style="width:100px;" value=''>


  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="title">
  <p><strong>mobile</strong></p>
   <input type="text" name="mobile" style="width:100px;" value=''>

  </div>
</div>


</div><!--row-->
</div><!--container-->
</br></br>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="Submit">


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojjEb.png
```

Comment: Why do you need input fields for retrieving data - you don't mention that part in question. Do you need it or it can be just representation of data?

Comment: Mr. Tpojka, I mention that i have to fetch data from data base and disply it in text box

Comment: Please fix your HTML basically. Pay attention how should [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) and [option](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) elements look like. Make [form](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) around input tags. You would use AJAX (jQuery recommended) to get data and populate your fields. See [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659934/codeigniter-dependent-dropdown-with-jquery-and-ajax-post). It's just you should populate input tags, but no option tags shown in accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Controller:

class Welcome extends CI_Controller 
{
  public function index()
  {
    $name = $this->input->post('website');
    $condition = "name =" . "'" . $name . "'";  

    // get person details
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('details');
    $this->db->where($condition);

    $data['result'] = $this->db->get();
    $this->load->view('organization','refresh',$data );       
  }



View:


<?php foreach ($result->result() as $row): ?>

  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="title">

     <p><strong>Fname</strong></p>

  <input type="text" name="Fname" style="width:100px;" value='<?=$row->f_name; ?>'>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
    <div class="title">
      <p><strong>Lname</strong></p>

      <input type="text" name="Lname" style="width:100px;" value='<?=$row->l_name; ?>'>

    </div>
  </div>

  <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: $condition = "name =" . "'" . $name . "'";

Comment: i tried your code i am getting Message: Undefined variable: result error