# dynamic select option in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I am creating dependable select option in codeigniter. To populate first option was easy but i am bit troubling in displaying the second option and third option. Need help on this

### My database contain:

In head table:
h_id, head fields, 
subhead table
h_id, sh_id, subhead fields and
points table
sh_id, points_name fields

---

### controller

```
class Mobile extends App_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper(array('url','language','form'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-red">', '</p>');
        $this->lang->load('auth');
        $this->load->model('mobiles_model'); 

    }
    function index()
    {
        if (!$this->data['logged_in']) 
        {
            redirect('auth/login','refresh');
        }

        $rows = $this->mobiles_model->get_users_devices();
        if ($rows) 
        {
            $this->data['devices_list'] = $rows;    
         }
        $this->_render_page('trackall', $this->data);       
    }

function _render_page($view, $data=null, $render=false)
    {

        $this->viewdata = (empty($data)) ? $this->data: $data;

        $view_html = $this->load->view($view, $this->viewdata, $render);

        if (!$render) return $view_html;
    }
}
```

### modal

```
public function get_users_devices()
            {   
                $this->db->select('A.h_id as id,A.head');
                $this->db->from($this->table_head.' as A'); 
                $query = $this->db->get();
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                return $query->result_array();
            }
            return FALSE;
            }
```

### view

```
<select id="head" name="head" class="form-control input-sm" onchange = "calljavascriptfunction();">
        <option value="default">--Select--</option>
        <?php if(isset($devices_list))
        foreach ($devices_list as $value) { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $value['h_id'] ?>"><?php echo $value['head'] ?></option>
         <?php } ?>                                   
      </select>


      <select id="subhead" name="subhead" class="form-control input-sm">
        <option value="default">--Select--</option>    


      </select>

 <select id="points" name="points" class="form-control input-sm">
        <option value="default">--Select--</option>    


      </select>
```

---

I have to populate the other depending on what i select. i tried several methods but none of them worked.
Thanks for help i am really stuck in this.

Comment: I think you need complete code of loading data in dependent dropdown.

Comment: yes i think so just stuck in the ajax call and ci

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659934/codeigniter-dependent-dropdown-with-jquery-and-ajax-post

Check this question and its solution.

Comment: already tried that, thanks

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3):

Suppose your you had following views loaded in HTML and you need to fetch value depending on first dropdown `#head`.

view code :

```
<select id="head">
    <option id="1"> Mobile </option>
    <option id="2"> Tabs </option>
    <option id="3"> Laptops </option>
</select>

<select id="subhead">
</select>
```

jquery ajax

```
$("#head").change(function(){

    var post_url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>mobile/getByDeviceId'
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        data : { "hid" : $(this).val() },
        success: function(response){
            $.each(response, function(value, key) {
                $("#subhead").append("<option id="+value.modelId+">"+value.modelName+"</option>");
            })
        }
    });
});
```

controller function :

```
function getByDeviceId(){

    $hid = $this->input->post("hid");

    $modelList = $this->mobile_model->getByDeviceId($hid);

    echo(json_encode($modelList));
}
```

model function :

```
function getByDeviceId($hid){

    $this->db->select("modelId, modelName");
    $this->db->from("models");
    $this->db->where("hid", $hid);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: please do this in success ```console.log(response);```, and check how you are receiving the response from server. You need to modify code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `ajax()` to do this, as `ajax()` do not disturb the current state of page and get the data from server and you can append it to the dropdown.

ajax() syntax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',                        
        type: 'POST',                                  
        data: {
            var1  :val1,
            var2  :val2
        },
        success: function(response){    // response from process
            // do your stuff here
        }
    });
```

Comment: $("#head").change(function() {
        var h_id = {"h_id" : $('#head').val()};

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: h_id,
          url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>mobile/ajax_get",
          success: function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(i, data) {
   $('#subhead').append("<option value='" + data.sh_id + "'>" + data.subhead + "</option>");
   });
  }
         });
       });

Comment: ```data : { "hId" : h_id }``` you need to send values like this.

Comment: data should be like `data: {
            var1  :val1,
            var2  :val2
        },`